# Архитектор, зодчий

Tags: этимология

У одной профессии сразу два названия. Как я понимаю, термин "архитектор" более современный и имеет греческое происхождение.
Но меня интересует слово "зодчий". Это русское слово? И, если да, какое у него происхождение - по звучанию угадать род занятия невозможно (в сравнении, например, с пекарем, уборщиком или конюхом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Зодчий" восходит к тому же корню, что и "здание", "созидать", и образовано так же, как слова "ловчий", "кравчий". Более подробно можно посмотреть у Фасмера, ещё подробнее расписано у Виноградова. Интересно, что слово "зодчий" считалось устаревшим уже в первой половине XIX века.